# Angular velocity after collision of two curling stones

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, velocity, collision

I am trying to create physics for game. I think I can figure out how the stones should move after collision...

[image]

however I am not sure how to figure out the angular velocity of stones after collision.
Given all the stones are same size and weight.

I think it has something to do with elastic collision of objects but it seem like this does not count in the friction. (My understanding is if two stone collide with no friction there would be no change in angular velocity) so clearly I am missing something. Googled for hours and hours but can not find anything related.

Any explanations or hints would be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not likely that the collision between two stones will conserve energy.  The equal and opposite forces which the stones exert on each other will have a strong normal component. It is probable that there will also be a perpendicular (friction) component. The angular impulse produced by friction (during the very short time of contact) would give each stone an angular velocity (and some of the kinetic energy). The friction might go from sliding to static and back to sliding. I know of no way of predicting this effect which would likely vary with the angle of impact.  I can only suggest observing a number of collisions to see how much rotation occurs.